# Apache Server will not start on MAMP

Tags: apache, windows-10, localhost, mamp

Im still very new to this so please go easy on me. When i click on MAMP, the light for the apache will turn on, then turn off but the mysql will remain on and work. But the localhost wont work, displaying the error **"localhost refused to connect."** 
I searched online and tried changing the port from 80 to the default 8888 but it still does not work. When i check the error logs on MAMP/logs/apache_error, and it displays

```
[warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[warn] pid file C:/MAMP/bin/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[notice] Digest: done
```

Please help, im using windows 10, im a complete newbie

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
I've changed PHP standard version from 7.3.7 to 7.2.14 and restarted. it worked.

Comment: Same case with me, installed MAMP, web start refused to connect, but when I changed the PHP standard to 7.2.14, now web start works.